# Data from dataset isn't displaying

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I use this code to make my report :

```
ReportDocument report;
MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();


using (SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        co.Open();

        cmd.Connection = co;
        cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = '{myId}'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.Fill(ds.person);

        co.Close();
    }
}

report = new ReportDocument();
report.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Reports\myReport.rpt");

report.SetDataSource(ds);
report.SetParameterValue("ID", myId);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

When I use this in a new project I have no problem, but when I try to use it in a project with already existing project the data don't load in the report even though the dataset is filled. When I try to actualise the report viewer a login dialog box appear and no matter what I use to login it fail and if I cancel the result is a blank page.

MyDataSet is using table that I took from my database in the server explorer.

So do I need to do something in case of solution with multiproject ?

EDIT :
By using this https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-33869, I no longer have the login dialog box but the data in my dataset still does not appear in the report.

Comment: your dataset type in report should be exactly same in report
I mean Namespace.MyDataSet (ds) should be added in your report

Comment: If you're talking about going in my .rpt and change the location of the datasource I did it.